# How to use 'is Supposed to' or 'was supposed to'

Tags: verbs, tenses

> Apparently Mary was supposed to be an insomniac.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: *Is supposed to* can substitute for either *is reputed to,* as in this case, or *ought to.* (In the latter case, the speaker is often subconsciously assuming intelligent and intentional design behind human and other nature, thus provoking the atheist or secularist to ask "supposed by whom?")

Comment: You need to provide context to your posts. This is way too broad.

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Just for laughs, check out http://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=donall+and+conall+meet+richard+dawkins+video&view=detail&mid=DDFC0C20FF3DAF17BB0CDDFC0C20FF3DAF17BB0C&FORM=VIRE1    What made me think of the video is your use of the word "secularist," which appears in the video with humorous effect in the phrase "sneaky little secularist." Don

Answer (score 3):

The sentence you have is grammatically correct, but it might be useful to keep in mind that "supposed to" has two subtly different connotations. In one, a person is expected or required to perform a task. In another, the person is regarded as having some quality, such as insomnia. As to the use of was/is, context from the rest of the passage will determine that: are you writing in the present or past tense? If Mary is no longer believed to be an insomniac, then she was supposed. If she currently has insomnia, then she is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

"Supposed to" (like the modals "may", "can", "must") has two different meanings: the *deontic*, about potentiality or compulsion in the world, and the *epistemic*, about our knowledge of the world.

So in some contexts "was supposed to" means "had to", or "was required to"; in other contexts it means "I heard that" or "people said that". Most times it is clear which one is intended, but sometimes it can be ambiguous.

So "Mary was supposed to be an insomniac" could in principle mean that it was her duty to be insomniac; but obviously that is a meaning which doesn't make sense in the real world, so here it must mean "I heard that ...", or "Somebody had told me that Mary was an insomniac". The "Apparently" reinforces the hearsay nature of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's correct because it's hard to know what you mean.  The sentence is ambiguous at best.

If by "supposed to be" you mean *supposedly*, then it is redundant, for "apparently" already covered that ground well enough.  You would instead simply write:

> Apparently, Mary was an insomniac.

Now, by "supposed to be," you could mean *should be*, but it's hard to imagine that someone *should be* an insomniac.  Nevertheless, as odd as it may be, if that's what you mean—maybe she's playing a role—you would write:

> Apparently, Mary was supposed to be an insomniac.

If that's not what you mean, that leaves only one possibility that is neither redundant nor queer, which is she was either *presumed* or *assumed* to be an insomniac, in which case, were I you, I would switch the verb to avoid all of this messy confusion about what you mean.  Either that or include whom by, whomever was supposing her to be an insomniac.  You might also consider taking that aspect out of the passive voice (was supposed) in order to actively show *who supposed*.